# Which models of face recognition deep learning?

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, python-3.5, conv-neural-network, knn

I need datasetCreator or "record face" to collect picture from users
How much picture i need to make face recognition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/ChristosChristofidis/awesome-deep-learning#datasets) you can find a lot of  deep learning resources.
Datasets for face recognition are:

- CMU PIE Database
- 10k US Adult Faces Database
- The AR Face Database, The Ohio State University
- ....

You will find much more.